# ruby gem nokogiri version 1.12.5 install error: 'gumbo.h' file not found

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I tried changing the gemfile to use a newer version of nokogiri as well as resolve dependencies by brew installing libxml2 and libslt, but nothing worked. Here is the error message:

```
gumbo.c:32:10: fatal error: 'gumbo.h' file not found
#include "gumbo.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: *** [gumbo.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Not a satisfying answer, but I uninstalled everything and did a clean install using `rbenv` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. After reading the nokogiri [installation instructions](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#supported-platforms), I learned something!

Nokogiri provides precompiled binaries for most things. Now if you switch from Mac to Linux or vice versa, your `Gemfile.lock` may have a platform list which doesn't include your current platform.

The command that fixed it for me was

`bundle lock --add-platform arm64-darwin`

Then, `bundle` just downloaded the *precompiled* version.

My recommendation is to work out how to install the precompiled version for your platform. When I ran `gem install nokogiri` that is what happened, but because of the platform list in the `Gemfile.lock` it wasn't doing that and instead wanted to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me on my M1 Macbook was by using `rbenv` but first:

1. Uninstall bundler: `gem uninstall bundler`
2. Uninstall rbenv: `rbenv uninstall YourRubyVersion`  and then `brew uninstall rbenv`

*(`YourRubyVersion` you can find it by executing `ruby -v`)*

3. Delete the  `Gemfile.lock` file.

After that:

`brew install rbenv`

`rbenv install RubyVersion`

`rbenv init`

`rbenv global RubyVersion`

`bundle install`